# Recent items not shown for Numbers app

Tags: mac, catalina

I have a `test.xlsx` file and the file is opened in Numbers app by default

When I go to `apple logo->recent items` then I see `Numbers.app` under `applications` section but I don't see the `test.xlsx` file either under the `documents` section or in the `Dock context menu` for the Numbers app icon in the dock or the Numbers.app's `Show Recents` option in dock

Comment: Go to `System Preferences -> General -> Recent Items`.  What number is displayed there?  If it's a small number, like 5, change to a higher number, then check for that test doc again.

Comment: @fsb: The value was 10. I changed it to 5 and set it back to 10. Now the `test.xlsx` file is being shown in apple logo->recent items. But it is still not displayed in the numbers.app icon in the Dock in the context menu or in show recents